# How do I set an OS X application bundle's working directory?

Tags: macos, bundle

Is there a key I can set in my application bundle to set what the working directory will be for the executable? It needs to be the **`$BUNDLE`/Contents/MacOS** directory (because of some library dependencies that do runtime loading that I can't easily modify).

I'm aware this can be done by wrapping with a script instead but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. However, you can just add an appropriate chdir() in your main() function before calling NSApplicationMain.